# future warning on pandas groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M')).agg({'Purchases':[ np.count_nonzero,np.sum]})

Tags: pandas, pd.grouper

python==3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

```
import pandas as pd #pandas==2.1.3
import numpy as np #numpy==1.26.1
```

dfcardtype:

```
     Date       Purchases    Credits    Card Type
9   2019-03-13       0.00     150.00         visa     
21  2019-04-13    2031.67       0.00         visa
27  2019-04-24    1311.00       0.00         visa
33  2019-05-09    1021.11       0.00         visa
36  2019-05-17    1860.00       0.00         visa

df = dfcardtype.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M')).agg({'Purchases':[ np.count_nonzero,np.sum]})
```

expected result: count and sum the Purchases column monthwise excluding zero cells

> FutureWarning: The provided callable <function sum at 0x000001A352B6B380> is currently using SeriesGroupBy.sum.
> In a future version of pandas, the provided callable will be used directly.
> To keep current behavior pass the string "sum" instead.

```
df = dfcardtype.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M')).agg({'Purchases':[ np.count_nonzero,np.sum]})
```

expected result: count and sum the Purchases column monthwise excluding zero cells

> FutureWarning: The provided callable <function sum at 0x000001A352B6B380> is currently using SeriesGroupBy.sum.
> In a future version of pandas, the provided callable will be used directly.
> To keep current behavior pass the string "sum" instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning is clear - use `sum` instead `np.sum`. Also for avoid `MultiIndex` is possible specify column after `groupby`:

```
df = (dfcardtype.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M'))['Purchases']
                    .agg([np.count_nonzero,'sum']))
print (df)
            count_nonzero      sum
Date                              
2019-03-31              0     0.00
2019-04-30              2  3342.67
2019-05-31              2  2881.11
```

Also is possible set custom columns names in output by [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation):

```
df = (dfcardtype.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M'))
                    .agg(Count_no_zero=('Purchases', np.count_nonzero),
                         Sum=('Purchases','sum')))
print (df)
            Count_no_zero      Sum
Date                              
2019-03-31              0     0.00
2019-04-30              2  3342.67
2019-05-31              2  2881.11
```

If need `MultiIndex` in columns use your solution:

```
df = (dfcardtype.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date',freq='M'))
                .agg({'Purchases':[ np.count_nonzero,'sum']}))
print (df)
               Purchases         
           count_nonzero      sum
Date                             
2019-03-31             0     0.00
2019-04-30             2  3342.67
2019-05-31             2  2881.11
```